# Exstract only postal code from geocoding

Tags: r, geocoding

I geocoded the address and I got a table like in below. How can I extract only postal_code?

```
library(googleway)
a <- google_geocode(address = '1208 3RD AVE S,NASHVILLE,TN', key = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN")

a$results$address_components
[[1]]
     long_name      short_name                                  types
1             1208            1208                          street_number
2 3rd Avenue South       3rd Ave S                                  route
3  South Nashville South Nashville                neighborhood, political
4        Nashville       Nashville                    locality, political
5  Davidson County Davidson County administrative_area_level_2, political
6        Tennessee              TN administrative_area_level_1, political
7    United States              US                     country, political
8            37210           37210                            postal_code
9             4104            4104                     postal_code_suffix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base` function:

```
subset(a$results$address_components[[1]], types == "postal_code")
```

Using `tidyverse`:

```
a$results$address_components[[1]] %>% filter(types == "postal_code")
```

But I guess you want to extract all of your list, thus you could use `lapply` to get a list of postal codes:

```
lapply(a$results, function(x){
  subset(x[[1]], types == "postal_code")[["short_name"]]
})
```

Or again `tidyverse` to get a data frame:

```
map(a$results, filter, .data = .[[1]], types == "postal_code") %>% 
  reduce(bind_rows) %>% 
  select(short_name) # optional...
```

Comment: Thanks for the great hint! Actually, I had to add [[1]] to make your code work. `subset(a$results$address_components[[1]], types == "postal_code")`

Comment: Glad it helped. I overlooked that other level of the list, sorry. Might not have happened with a reproducible example ;-) Consider to accept the answer, if it now works for you, thanks.